# Display calculation results from AJAX query

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In this ROR application I am attempting to display/redisplay a results calculation if the user changes any of the input values.  Using the Developer Tools on Chrome I can determine the appropriate results have been calculated and returned using the Javascript below.  I am able to pick a change in any of the input values and redo the calculations.  However I am unable to get the Javascript to display the results.

Below I have added the Javascript, the relevant part of the views (one main - one partial) as well as the relevant part of the controller.

The javascript - drill.js.coffee
I am reasonably certain I am missing something which wold enable me to place the appropriate code in the place I indicate with ???

```
$('document').ready ->
  if $('#evaluation_assumption_params').length == 1
    drill_id = $('.form.assumption').attr('data-drillid')
    $('#evaluation_assumption_params').change((event) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      loadAssumptionChange drill_id
     )

loadAssumptionChange = (drill_id)->
  data = $('#evaluation_assumption_params').serialize()
  console.log data
  $.ajax
    url:"/drills/#{drill_id}/projection.json"
    type:"post"
    dataType: 'json'
    data: data
    success: (data,success,xhr)->

    # ??? - tried numerous statements including 
    # $('#place_to_add_projection_results').html(data)
    # $('#ajax').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'drills/evaluation_results')).html_safe %>")
      # What should go here ???
```

the partial - _assessment_results.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for :result_list, :html => { class: 'infogroup', id: "evaluation_results", :method => :post },
      remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= content_tag :header, "Results", class: 'infogroup-header'%>  
  <%= content_tag :div, class: 'infogroup-body' do %> 
    <%= content_tag :table, class: 'info', border: 0, cellspacing: 5, cellpadding: 0 do %>     
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>SP</th>
        <th>Mkt Cap</th>
        ...
      </tr>
      <% if @result_list.present? %>
        <% @result_list.each do |result| %>                 
          <tr>
            <td><%= result.listing_name %></td>
            <td><%= number_to_currency(result.listing.share_price_dollars,
                  :precision => 3, :delimiter => ',')     %></td> 
     …
```

the main screen corresponding to controller action - investor.html.erb
The partial above invoked by this screen as well as the javascript

```
<% content_for :title, "Drill Investor - Valuations" %>
… more heading stuff
<section>
  <div class="form assumption" data-drillid="<%= @drill.id %>">
      <%= render 'assumption_params' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form">
      <div id="place_to_add_projection_results">
        <%= render 'evaluation_results' %>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The controller

```
class DrillsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :current_user
  ...  
  def investor
      # screens associated allow entry of data as well as display of the results
  end

  def projection
    result_list = Evaluation.generate_projection(@drill.drill_interests, assumption_params)
    render json: result_list
  end
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are getting a list, so you would have to iterate over the results and append each result to your container div, for simplicity purposes, I would do something similar to this inside your success ajax callback:

```
var $container_div = $("#place_to_add_projection_results");
$container_div.empty(); // First clear div just in case
var evaluations = xhr.responseJSON;
$.each(evaluations, function(i, evaluation) {
  $container_div.append("<div"> + evaluation.X + ", " + evaluation.Z +" </div>");
});
```

Where X, Z, are some properties from your model.

Comment: Hi DevDude, Thanks for answering the question.   I tried to mark it up but I have only 5 reputation oints (you need 15).